# Concatenate strings in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to concatenate two strings. However, the code below

```
set string = string1 || string2 
set string = concat (string1, string2)
```

returns null if one of the strings is null. I would like to return the other string if one of the strings is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another option is

```
set string = coalesce(string1 || string2, string1, string2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior of concat. According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#concat):

> The function returns NULL if any input argument is NULL

To avoid this, you can use the [`IFNULL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#ifnull) function before concat:

```
set string = ifnull(string1, '') || ifnull(string2, '')
```

Comment: The drawback of this approach is that returns a non null value if both strings are null.

Comment: Yes, if you need to keep null case both are null, a solution could be: `if(a is null, b, if(b is null, a, a || b))`